# How to access a executable file in jar

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

my project folder is like

```
├── bin
│   ├── org...
│   └── resources
│       └──driver
├──src
│   └──org...
└── resources
    └──driver
```

...

where driver is an excitable file.
How can I use that program in my java project, especially when I export it as a JAR?

I tried

```
...
java.net.URL driverURL = this.getClass().getResource("/resources/driver");
cmd[0] = driverURL.toString();
process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

But it won't work.

I read about some articles saying how to access resources using inputStream, but I wonder how to access an executable file?

Comment: I'm going to assume you must put it somewhere first then run it. Since it's a `resource` not a `executable file`

Comment: Sorry I was not aware the detail of a 'resource'. It is a executable file. But I want to put it together with my java program, not a specific address on my computer.

Comment: Right so its in packed in with the jar but its a resource.... so you will need to get it as a `stream` and then start reading from that stream and save it to a temp file somewhere then you will need to get the path `(you should already know the path)` and execute it.

Comment: So you mean I should copy that file by binary. Can I run it directly?

Comment: I have no clue if you can run it directly.. maybe you can just read it into memory or something and run it there. I would look further into that but other than that you would probably have to `recreate` the file then run it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a plugin use:

```
Bundle bundle = .... your plugin bundle

URL url = FileLocator.find(bundle, new Path("/resources/driver"), null);

url = FileLocator.toFileURL(url);

String cmd = url.getFile();

Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

`FileLocator.find` returns you a URL for anything in the plugin, but this URL is often an internal Eclipse format URL.

`FileLocator.toFileURL` converts the URL to a 'file' URL, this may involve copying the object from the plugin Jar to a temporary location.

You can get the `Bundle` using:

```
Bundle bundle = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(getClass());
```

or

```
Bundle bundle = Platform.getBundle("plugin id");
```

The `FrameworkUtil` method always returns the bundle for the plugin containing the class, the second method can get the bundle for any class.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. That worked. I can find the temporary file, though it is no longer executable (but is executable in debug mode as it is in my workspace). Any suggestion?

Comment: p.s. I used `URL driverURL = this.getClass().getResource("/resource/driver");` rather than Bundle as url would be null.

Comment: I used a process to execute `chmod +x` after I got the fileURL. I think it already solved my issue if there is no better way. Than you.